# Configuring Ruby On Rails App in a subdirectory under Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, windows-server-2003

I've got apache2.2 on windows. I'm trying to serve both subversion (/svn) and redmine (/redmine). I have svn running fine with this config:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath C:/svn_repository
  ...
</Location>
```

This is working great--my svn users can hit http://mybox/svn just fine.

Now I want to add another directory for a rails app (RedMine):

I followed the advice in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148838/how-do-i-configure-apache-2-2-for-ruby-on-rails-in-windows) to setup a mongrel server and have apache proxy clients through to it. It works fine if I make it the root--but I'm having trouble making it in a subdirectory:

```
<Location /redmine>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
</Location>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's what I had to change:

I removed the trailing slash:

```
<Location /redmine>
  ProxyPass http://localhost:3000
  ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
</Location>
```

And in my rails app:

```
# added to end of file C:\redmine\config\environment.rb
ActionController::AbstractRequest.relative_url_root = "/redmine"
```

Now it's working!

---

I wasn't completely happy with this approach--I ran into some redirect issues. This is another attempt which seems to be working well so far.

- [Fast CGI](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/Fast+CGI+and+Apache2+for+Windows+XP) and [Fast CGI without VirtualHosts](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/Fast+CGI+and+Apache2+for+Windows+without+VirtualHosts)
- [Tuning Fast CGI](http://scottstuff.net/blog/articles/2005/07/20/apache-tuning-for-rails-and-fastcgi)

This second approach seems better.

---

**UPDATE:**

As noted in the comments, for more recent apps running on Rails 2.3.2+, use this instead:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/redmine'
```

I put it in the new `additional_environment.rb` file.

Comment: I would strongly recommend Passenger. Makes hosting rails almost as easy as PHP.

Comment: I'm on windows so I don't think that will work for me. Thanks, though.

Comment: It's actually ActionController::Base.relative_url_root since Rails 2.3.x

Comment: Do you have to set a different port for every Rails app?

Comment: @Olivier I only have it running under a different port (3000) because apache is running on port 80. If you host multiple rails apps with the same webserver, you'd use the same port for all

Answer (score 1):

In case you still wish to use Mongrel + Apache using a reverse proxy here is how I solved the same issue on our system (Win2k3, Apache 2.2, trunk of Redmine). The secret is to install your mongrel service using `--prefix /redmine` which tells it to serve it from `http://localhost:port/redmine`

In Apache httpd.conf (or suitable include file):

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
ProxyRequests Off
#No need to forward on static content - let apache do it faster
ProxyPass /redmine/images ! 
ProxyPass /redmine/stylesheets ! 
ProxyPass /redmine/javascript ! 
# Remove the following entry on public sites as this is insecure
ProxyPass /redmine/plugin_assets !
ProxyPass /redmine/help ! 
ProxyPass /redmine http://localhost:4000/redmine
ProxyPassReverse /redmine http://localhost:4000/redmine
ProxyPreserveHost On
#continue with other static files that should be served by apache
Alias /redmine/images C:/Repositories/redmine/public/images/
Alias /redmine/stylesheets C:/Repositories/redmine/public/stylesheets/
Alias /redmine/javascript C:/Repositories/redmine/public/javascript/
# Remove the following on public sites as this is insecure
Alias /redmine/plugin_assets C:/Repositories/redmine/public/plugin_assets/
Alias /redmine/help C:/Repositories/redmine/public/help/
</IfModule>

# Make sure apache can see public and all subfolders - not suitable for public sites
<Directory "C:/Repositories/redmine/public/">
    Allow from all
    Order allow,deny
</Directory>
```

Mongrel is installed as such:

```
mongrel_rails service::install --prefix /redmine -N redmine_prod -p 4000 -e production -c C:\Repositories\redmine
```

Hope that helps someone. Initially, I tried setting up Apache + fastcgi etc but I lost more precious hair - it's not Windows friendly.

P.s. I found this PDF a very useful referene: http://www.napcsweb.com/howto/rails/deployment/RailsWithApacheAndMongrel.pdf

/Damien

Answer (score 0):

Passenger (http://modrails.com) is a better alternative to fastcgi because it's very easy to configure I would recommend using this for hosting your rails apps using a similar configuration to what you have now

Comment: Even so, it's the first Google result and Michael added the windows2003 tag over 3 hours ago.

Comment: And what does windows2003 have to do with it? Passenger works.

Comment: According to the passenger site windows is not supported. If it is, please provide a link saying so and I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Radar. [Passenger](http://www.modrails.com/) is really easy to set up, lets Rails apps share memory, removes the burden of managing a cluster of mongrels and requires virtually no configuration. All you need are a special 'config.ru' file with a [RackUp config](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide.html#_rackup_specifications_for_various_web_frameworks) and a DocumentRoot pointing to RAILS_ROOT/public set in Apache.

Comment: No - with no planned support for Windows either it appears. See http://bitnami.org/forums/forums/2/topics/477