# How to install Ruby on Rails alongside WampServer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, wamp, wampserver

Is is possible to install Ruby on Rails alongside [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) (and keep WampServer's Apache/MySQL installs)?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I installed Ruby on Rails alongside WampServer. Here is how to do it:

Replace `C:\wamp\` in the following text by your own WampServer's install repository.

Installing Ruby:

1. Download Ruby. Use the Windows **binary** version, not the "one click installer" because it contains MySQL and Apache which we don't need.
2. Extract the zip to `C:\wamp\ruby\`.
3. Add Ruby's bin repository in your PATH environment variable:

   1. Right click "Computer / Properties".
   2. Click "Advanced System Settings".
   3. Advanced tab / Environment Variables.
   4. Append `;C:\wamp\ruby\bin` to the Path variable.

Installing DevKit:

Download DevKit:

1. Extract DevKit to `c:\wamp\ruby\DevKit`.
2. `cd /d c:\wamp\ruby\DevKit`.
3. `ruby dk.rb init`.

   - Add `- c:\wamp\ruby` to the end of `config.yml`.
4. `ruby dk.rb install`

Installing Rails and the Mongrel server:

1. Open the command line and type:

   ```
   gem install rails
   ```
2. Create your first Rails application by opening the command line from `C:\wamp\www\rails\` and typing:

   ```
   rails hello
   ```
3. Install the Mongrel server and Windows Mongrel service, making sure to run the command line as administrator:

   ```
   gem install mongrel and 
   gem install mongrel_service
   ```
4. Install a Windows service for your Rails application:

   ```
   mongrel_rails service::install -N ruby-hello -c c:\wamp\www\rails\hello -p 3001 -e development
   ```
5. Start your Mongrel service:

   ```
   net start ruby-hello
   ```

You can now access your Rails application at `http://localhost:3001/`.

Integrating with Apache

1. Enable mod_proxy in httpd.conf

   Open httpd.conf (c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.x.x\conf\httpd.conf) and uncomment the following line:

   ```
   LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
   ```
2. Forward your traffic to your Mongrel server. Add the following text to your httpd.conf (or extra/httpd-vhosts.conf if it's included in your httpd.conf):

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName hello.com
   ServerAlias *.hello.com
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
3. Add hello.com to your hosts file.  Open `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` in Notepad and add the following line:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 www.hello.com hello.com
   ```

You can now go to http://www.hello.com and it should load your Rails application.

References:

- http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads
- http://www.wampserver.com
- http://www.ruby-lang.org
- http://mongrel.rubyforge.org and http://mongrel.rubyforge.org/wiki/Win32

Comment: @Oliver Lalonde: I'm trying to follow these steps to get the same result but I've run into some problems. Did you have RubyGems installed before doing this? I got this error when trying to `gem install rails`: missing dlls `ssleay32.dll` and `zlib.dll`; followed http://alwaysthecritic.typepad.com/atc/2009/03/install-ruby-191-on-windows.html, got the dlls, now missing readline.dll.

Comment: I can't find the binaries you were talking about 

`Download Ruby (the Windows binary version, not the "one click installer"

Comment: Thank you I've been searching for this I'll let you know if it works.

Comment: the binary from garbagecollect or what? from here: ftp://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/binaries/mswin32/ruby-1.9.2-p136-i386-mswin32.zip ?

Comment: I'm having error with the 4th step on installing mongrel_rails service. It says that a specific module could not be found. - c:/wamp/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/http11.so

Comment: I'm having same problem as freeloaded:
"I'm having error with the 4th step on installing mongrel_rails service. It says that a specific module could not be found. - c:/wamp/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongrel-1.1.5-x86-mingw32/lib/http11.so"
Any solution?

Comment: I tried this and got Error 500 Internal Server Error. Please help?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, There is [InstantRails](http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/wiki/wiki.pl)

Comment: Doesn't InstantRails install Apache and MySQL as well ? I wouldn't want to keep 2 different installs of Apache and MySQL.

Comment: I meant for easy installation and all-in-one standlone for Windows, Yes, Its just have everything like WAMP, or XAMPP.

Answer (score 5):

This is assuming you're trying to set up a development environment, because it doesn't make much sense to use Windows and/or WAMP for a production server.

You can instally Ruby rather easily on Windows using the [Ruby installer](http://rubyinstaller.org/). There's also the [one-click installer](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/) which includes a number of libraries (though you can install these yourself with rubygems later).

You are correct in that you install Rails (and dependencies) as a gem.

Now, as for Apache... I'm going to suggest that you keep your WAMP installation and simply don't use it for Ruby/Rails. Ruby has a built-in web server called WEBrick, and there's another light-weight server called Mongrel (available as a gem). These can be run simultaneously with Apache, with Apache serving PHP content and Mongrel/WEBrick serving Rails. They'll run on different ports (Apache on 80, Mongrel/WEBrick on 3000 by default), so there shouldn't be any conflicts.

There are several advantages with this approach:

1. You won't have to mess with your WAMP installation and risk screwing something up.
2. Running applications from different languages separately protects them from each other. For example, if your Rails app crashes the server, it won't bring your PHP stuff down with it in case you're running both.
3. Thirdly, most popular Rails IDEs (RubyMine, Aptana, etc) have built-in controls for both or one of the Mongrel and WEBrick servers. This means that you'll be able to start/stop/restart your server within the IDE, as well as display the output/logs. For Rails development in Windows, I recommend RubyMine.

MySQL is separate from Apache, so your Rails app will be able to access MySQL databases regardless of which server is serving its content. Naturally, you'll have to run at least the MySQL version of WAMP in order for it to work.

Answer (score 3):

## To install+run **Ruby On Rails** application on localhost (wampserver or etc):

USE standalone Ruby Server installations: a) http://railsinstaller.org/en b) http://www.helicontech.com/zoo/install.html  c) https://bitnami.com/stack/ruby

**OR**


1) Install **WAMP** (or etc)

2) Install [Ruby](http://rubyinstaller.org/)

3) open  ...wamp\bin\apache\apache**XXXX**\conf\**httpd.conf**, then search & replace

`Options Indexes FollowSymLinks` 

with

`Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI` (or `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI`)

p.s. also, Find & ensure that **LoadModule cgi_module** is NOT commented.

4) search & replace

`#AddHandler cgi-script .cgi`

 with  (...removing **#** )

`AddHandler cgi-script .cgi` 

`AddHandler cgi-script .rb`

5) Find the line:
`DirectoryIndex index.php index.php3 index.html index.htm`

 and add in the end of them:  `index.cgi index.rb` 

 Now, **Restart Apache**.

6) create a **sample.rb** (in /www root), with such content:

```
#!C:\Ruby200\bin\ruby\ruby.exe
puts "Content-type: text/html" #in newer version, might be puts("....")
puts ""
puts "Test Pageeeeeeeee."
```

p.s. NOTE: 
(a) Change **C:|Ruby..** path to your RUBY installation path correctly.   (b) To avoid problems, dont install RUBY in a path, wherein any "folder name" contains a space. (c) There should not be a space between the start of line and **print(..**

7) open `http://localhost/sample.rb`

**THAT's all**!!

p.s.*note, in come cases, while using .htaccess [inside .rb directory], you might need to insert these lines in .htaccess:*

`Options +ExecCGI`

`AddHandler cgi-script .rb`