# Can't install Ruby on Rails on Wamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I followed this tutorial:

[How to install Ruby on Rails alongside WampServer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025449/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-alongside-wampserver)

After adding `D:\wamp\ruby\bin` (my wamp folder is in D:) to my Path and write `gem install rails` in the command line I get 2 error which says that the following files couldn't be found:

```
SSLEAY32.dll
zlib.dll
```

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Never mind it is fixed by downloading some dlls http://alwaysthecritic.typepad.com/atc/2009/03/install-ruby-191-on-windows.html