# Run RoR on WAMP or on apache under windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, apache, wamp, webrick

Is it possible to run ror on apache under windows environment? I am having so much trouble with webrick server lately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do so with Passenger / mod_rails.

Here's a relevant Stack Overflow answer:

[How to install Ruby on Rails alongside WampServer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025449/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-alongside-wampserver)