# gem install rails build error failed to build gem native extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, wamp

My main goal is to make Redmine work along with WAMPServer. I followed these steps : [How to install Ruby on Rails alongside WampServer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025449/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-alongside-wampserver?lq=1)

When i have to install rails, a build error seems to happen in my command line

Here's my error :

> c:\wamp\ruby\gem install rails
>
> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
>
> Building native extensions. This could take a while...
>
> ERROR: Error installing tzinfo:
>
> ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> C:/wamp/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
>   creating Makefile
>
> make
>   gcc -I. -I. -IC:/wamp/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32 -I.  -g -O2 -DFD_SETSIZE=256    -c atomic_reference.c
>   atomic_reference.c: In function 'ir_compare_and_set':
>   atomic_reference.c:75:2: error: #error No CAS operation available for this platform
>   make: *** [atomic_reference.o] Error 1

I use Windows 7 64 bits and my versions are ruby 1.8.7, gem 1.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to install any gems at all? If not, then possibly its a problem with the configuration.

If you installed the devkit in the standard way, then the culprit could be incorrect Autorun regex key OR the incorrect command processor set by other tools that interferes with ruby gem installations.

Try the instructions here, and your issue should be solved: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-gems_fails_comspec_autorun

Let know if you still get the error(s).

Comment: Still get the error (i hadnt change anything, everything was ok on my side for both scenarios) . I think the problems comes from the fact that gems uses mingw32 while im on x64 platform

Comment: That shouldn't affect. Both ruby and gems are supported on x32 & x64 platforms. Did you look at other troubleshooting tips on the link above as well?

Comment: I finally resolved my problem by using the Ruby one click installer. I was using the Windows Binary Archive. However, some tracks can be found there : https://github.com/headius/ruby-atomic/issues/30

Comment: Good to know :). Thanks for sharing the issue track.