# Rails racc gem build failed to build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been following this tutorial to get ruby and rails on my mac m1 laptop (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jT_SPPPhRBk) but have not had any luck.

As soon as I get to `rails new myappname` I get a gem build extension error.

```
Fetching racc 1.5.2
Installing racc 1.5.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/racc-1.5.2/ext/racc/cparse
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/ruby -I /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/2.6.0
-r ./siteconf20211016-65058-14ute0m.rb extconf.rb
checking for rb_ary_subseq()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:467:in `try_do': The compiler
failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:552:in `try_link0'
    from /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:570:in `try_link'
    from /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:782:in `try_func'
from /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1069:in `block in
have_func'
from /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:959:in `block in
checking_for'
from /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block (2 levels)
in postpone'
    from /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
from /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:361:in `block in
postpone'
    from /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:331:in `open'
    from /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:357:in `postpone'
    from /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:958:in `checking_for'
    from /Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/2.6.0/mkmf.rb:1068:in `have_func'
    from extconf.rb:6:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
be found here:

/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.6.0-static/racc-1.5.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/racc-1.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to
/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.6.0-static/racc-1.5.2/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing racc (1.5.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install racc -v '1.5.2' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`
succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails was resolved to 6.1.4.1, which depends on
    actioncable was resolved to 6.1.4.1, which depends on
      actionpack was resolved to 6.1.4.1, which depends on
        actionview was resolved to 6.1.4.1, which depends on
          rails-dom-testing was resolved to 2.0.3, which depends on
            nokogiri was resolved to 1.12.5, which depends on
              racc
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)' in any of the gem sources listed in your
Gemfile.
       rails  webpacker:install
Could not find gem 'sqlite3 (~> 1.4)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

I tried the solution of `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21608611/gem-install-rails-build-error-failed-to-build-gem-native-extension` but this gives me a 'Operation Not Permitted' error.

I've also installed xcode and tried that without luck. Same error continues to occur.

I do have wamp installed and see that in the log above, but not sure if that has anything to do with it.

All I want to do is get it installed so I can start learning Rails... so this is very frustrating.

Additional error found in the mkmf.log

```
"clang -o conftest -I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include/ruby-2.6.0/x86_64-darwin16 -I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include/ruby-2.6.0/ruby/backward -I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include/ruby-2.6.0 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -pipe conftest.c  -L. -L/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib -L. -fstack-protector-strong     -lruby.2.6-static -framework Security -framework Foundation -lpthread -ldl -lobjc   "
ld: library not found for -lruby.2.6-static
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */
```

Comment: did you look at the contents of `/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-16/2.6.0-static/racc-1.5.2/mkmf.log` ?

Comment: added log details to question

Comment: Seems like the key line here is "You have to install development tools first.". You might try `xcode-select --install`